# Number of months since last email received

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the below table that shows a monthly view of customers that received an email in a particular month.

| cust_id | eom_date | email_sent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-30 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-05-31 |  |
| 1 | 2023-04-30 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-31 |  |
| 1 | 2023-02-28 |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-31 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-06-30 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-05-31 |  |
| 2 | 2023-04-30 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-03-31 |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-28 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-31 |  |
| 2 | 2022-12-31 | 1 |

I need to find out the number of months that has passed since the last email a customer received. This is the desired outcome:

| cust_id | eom_date | email_sent | months_since_last_email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-30 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-05-31 |  | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-04-30 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-03-31 |  | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-02-28 |  | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-31 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-06-30 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-05-31 |  | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-04-30 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-03-31 |  | 3 |
| 2 | 2023-02-28 |  | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-01-31 |  | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-12-31 | 1 | 0 |

I tried the below in BigQuery but it only gives me cust_ids for previous periods, basically getting nowhere:

```
SELECT cust_id, 
       eom_date,
       lag(cust_id, 1) over (
         partition by cust_id order by eom_date) t1,
       lag(cust_id, 2) over (
         partition by cust_id order by eom_date) t2
  FROM table
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for SQL Server. Don't have BigQuery, but these are pretty commonly supported functions.

The general idea should work for BigQuery using date_diff instead of datediff

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/Hor4MnrD

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
    cust_id INT,
    eom_date DATE,
    email_sent INT
);

INSERT INTO your_table_name (cust_id, eom_date, email_sent)
VALUES 
(1, '2023-06-30', 1),
(1, '2023-05-31', NULL),
(1, '2023-04-30', 1),
(1, '2023-03-31', NULL),
(1, '2023-02-28', NULL),
(1, '2023-01-31', 1),
(2, '2023-06-30', 1),
(2, '2023-05-31', NULL),
(2, '2023-04-30', 1),
(2, '2023-03-31', NULL),
(2, '2023-02-28', NULL),
(2, '2023-01-31', NULL),
(2, '2022-12-31', 1);
```

Option A: Correlated subquery. Find the last email sent by cust_id and take the date diff.

```
select *,
       datediff(
       month,
       (
         select max(t2.eom_date)
           from your_table_name t2
          where t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id
            and t1.eom_date >= t2.eom_date
            and t2.email_sent = 1
          group
             by t2.cust_id
       ),
       eom_date) as months_since_last_email
  from your_table_name t1
 order
    by cust_id,
       eom_date desc;
```

Option B: Window function. Send non-email months as null, so the max in the unbounded preceding window will be the last sent date.

```
select *,
       datediff(
       month,
       max(case when email_sent = 1 then 
                     eom_date
            end
          ) over ( partition by cust_id
                       order by eom_date
                      rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                 ),
       eom_date) as months_since_last_email
  from your_table_name t1
 order
    by cust_id,
       eom_date desc;
```